# Java: Rock, Paper, Scissors almost completed but has a fatal error

Tags: java, if-statement, nested, switch-statement

I was tasked to create a java program that resembles rock, paper, scissors. I have written what I thought would work below. However, only when the user selects R or r (for rock) does it actually work properly. If the user selects s or p (scissors or paper) the code will completely break or give multiple answers. I have looked through the code and can't seem to find out why it's not working properly.

Also any suggestions on how to better write the switch portion of the code would be appreciated. I have a feeling the way I wrote it is not the proper way.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int compVal = (int) (3 * Math.random()) + 1;
        String compActual = "";
        System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!");
        System.out.print("Enter r for rock, p for paper, or s for scissors: ");
        String userOriginal = keyboard.nextLine();
        userOriginal = (userOriginal.toUpperCase());
        switch (userOriginal) {
        case "r":
            userOriginal = userOriginal;
            break;
        case "R":
            userOriginal = userOriginal;
            break;
        case "p":
            userOriginal = userOriginal;
            break;
        case "P":
            userOriginal = userOriginal;
            break;
        case "s":
            userOriginal = userOriginal;
            break;
        case "S":
            userOriginal = userOriginal;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input, please try again!");
            System.exit(1); // This will exit the program if invalid input is
                            // given. The 1 signifies that it ended with an
                            // error.
        }
        if (compVal == 1) {
            compActual = "R";
        } else if (compVal == 2) {
            compActual = "P";
        } else if (compVal == 3) {
            compActual = "S";
        }
        if (compActual.equals(userOriginal)) {
            System.out.println("It was a tie!");
        } else if (compActual.equals("R"))
            if (userOriginal.equals("S")) {
                System.out.println("You played Scissors and I chose Rock: Rock crushes Scissors so I win this time!");
            }
        if (userOriginal.equals("P")) {
            System.out.println("You played Paper and I chose Rock: Paper covers Rock so you win this time!");
        } else if (compActual.equals("S"))
            if (userOriginal.equals("R")) {
                System.out.println("You played Rock and I chose Sciccors: Rock crushes Scissors so you win this time");
            }
        if (userOriginal.equals("P")) {
            System.out.println("You played Paper and I chose Scissors: Paper is cut by Scissors so I win this time!");
        } else if (compActual.equals("P"))
            if (userOriginal.equals("R")) {
                System.out.println("Your played Rock and I chose Paper: Paper covers rock so I win this time!");
            }
        if (userOriginal.equals("S")) {
            System.out.println("You played Scissors and I chose Paper: Scissors cuts Paper so you win this time!");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why all the `userOriginal = userOriginal`?

Comment: I've formatted your code for readability, but in the future I strongly recommend that you do this yourself, especially by giving your code proper indentations, usually 4 spaces per block, and making sure that all code on the same block is on the same indentation level. Formatting is very important because if your code is not in a standard accepted format, it's not very readable, and if it's not readable, it's not understandable.

Comment: The reason I used userOriginal = userOriginal was to find out if there was invalid input from the user. For example; if the user enter q instead of the desired input the program would terminate. I didn't know what to say after a case if the user entered the correct value so I wrote something that would do nothing

Comment: I would just leave it blank or better use a logger to log the state of your program when needed depending on the log state, anything other than use of distracting nonsense code such as you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, you should clean up your code a little bit. Why not use numerical values instead of Strings for comparsion, like this:

```
        int compVal = (int) (3 * Math.random()) + 1;
        int userOriginal = 0;
        String userInput = (keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase());

        switch (userInput) {
        case "R":
            userOriginal = 1;
            break;
        case "P":
            userOriginal = 2;
            break;
        case "S":
            userOriginal = 3;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input, please try again!");
            System.exit(1); // This will exit the program
        }
```

After that you can compare the user provided value with the generated one:

```
        if (compVal == userOriginal) {
            System.out.println("It was a tie!");
        } else
        {
            //R
            if (compVal == 1)
            {
                if (userOriginal == 2) {
                    System.out.println("You played Paper and I chose Rock: Paper covers Rock so you win this time!");
                }
                if (userOriginal == 3) {
                    System.out.println("You played Scissors and I chose Rock: Rock crushes Scissors so I win this time!");
                }
            }
            //P 
            if (compVal == 2)
            {
                if (userOriginal == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Your played Rock and I chose Paper: Paper covers rock so I win this time!");
                }
                if (userOriginal == 3) {
                    System.out.println("You played Scissors and I chose Paper: Scissors cuts Paper so you win this time!");
                }
            }
            //S
            if (compVal == 3)
            {
                if (userOriginal == 1) {
                    System.out.println("You played Rock and I chose Sciccors: Rock crushes Scissors so you win this time");
                }
                if (userOriginal == 2) {
                    System.out.println("You played Paper and I chose Scissors: Paper is cut by Scissors so I win this time!");
                }
            }
        }
```

Also, remember to always close all the resources that you used:

```
keyboard.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple commands after an if-statement, but you're missing the {}.
For instance:

```
 else if (compActual.equals("R"))
            if (userOriginal.equals("S"))
            {
            System.out.println("You played Scissors and I chose Rock: Rock crushes Scissors so I win this time!");
            }
            if (userOriginal.equals("P"))
            {
            System.out.println("You played Paper and I chose Rock: Paper covers Rock so you win this time!");
            }
```

should be:

```
 else if (compActual.equals("R")) 
 {
            if (userOriginal.equals("S"))
            {
            System.out.println("You played Scissors and I chose Rock: Rock crushes Scissors so I win this time!");
            }
            if (userOriginal.equals("P"))
            {
            System.out.println("You played Paper and I chose Rock: Paper covers Rock so you win this time!");
            }
 }
```

and, I'm sorry to say, you code needs cleaning up. For instance, you're using toUpperCase(), so no need to compare with lower case input.

Comment: Thank you Michael D. That is what I needed. Do you have another suggestion for how to handle invalid input instead of creating code that does nothing? For example; if the user enter q instead of the desired input the program would terminate. I didn't know what to say after a case if the user entered the correct value so I wrote something that would do nothing

Answer (score 0):

First: what does should do your first switch (on userOrigignal values)?
If is is way to check if values is correct you have better way - create collection of possible values ("R", "P", "S") and check input against this collections:

```
private static final Collection<String> TYPES = new HashSet<>();
static {
    TYPES.add("R");
    TYPES.add("P");
    TYPES.add("S");
}

private static boolean correctInput(String input) {
    TYPES.contains(input.toUpperCase());
}
```

so you could replace this awful switch with simple call to function correctInput.

Next problem - you wrote totally wrong if's block: for example `if (compActual.equals("R"))` cases not surrounded with braces. So you checked R against S and after it simple entry for user "P"... It is better way to surround every if's body with braces - in this case you won't be confused by stylings and will see exact if's bodies.

And last problem - don't closed Scanner object. In current program it wouldn't bring any problem, but it is strongly recommended to always close resources.

PS you can make it much easelly with prepared table:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Project_2 {
private static final Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> TYPES = new HashMap<>();
static {
    Map<Integer, String> subMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    subMap.put(0, "It was a tie!");
    subMap.put(1, "You played Rock and I chose Scissors: Rock crushes Scissors so you win this time");
    subMap.put(2, "Your played Rock and I chose Paper: Paper covers rock so I win this time!");
    TYPES.put("R", subMap);

    subMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    subMap.put(0, "You played Scissors and I chose Rock: Rock crushes Scissors so I win this time!");
    subMap.put(1, "It was a tie!");
    subMap.put(2, "You played Scissors and I chose Paper: Scissors cuts Paper so you win this time!");
    TYPES.put("S", subMap);

    subMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    subMap.put(0, "You played Paper and I chose Rock: Paper covers Rock so you win this time!");
    subMap.put(1, "You played Paper and I chose Scissors: Paper is cut by Scissors so I win this time!");
    subMap.put(2, "It was a tie!");
    TYPES.put("P", subMap);
}

private static boolean checkInput(String input) {
    TYPES.containsKey(input.toUpperCase());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int compVal = new Random().nextInt(3);
    System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!");
    System.out.print("Enter r for rock, p for paper, or s for scissors: ");
    String userOriginal = null;
    try (Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        userOriginal = keyboard.nextLine();
    }

    if (!checkInput(userOriginal)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input, please try again!");
        System.exit(1); // This will exit the program if invalid input is
                        // given. The 1 signifies that it ended with an
                        // error.
    }
    System.out.println(TYPES.get(userOriginal, compVal));
}
```

}